# Why does the value interpolation not work when using python hydra library?

Tags: fb-hydra, hydra-core

I modify the [config.yaml](https://github.com/facebookresearch/hydra/blob/main/examples/tutorials/basic/your_first_hydra_app/6_composition/conf/config.yaml) form the tutorials in the [hydra](https://github.com/facebookresearch/hydra/tree/main) repository as follows:

```
defaults:
  - db: mysql
  - ui: full
  - schema: school

test_key: ${db.user}
```

However, the `test_key` is still `${db.user}` in the output without being replaced by the actual value `omry`.
I type the command `python my_app.py` in the [folder](https://github.com/facebookresearch/hydra/tree/main/examples/tutorials/basic/your_first_hydra_app/6_composition).

Comment: This is not a question related to YAML, because for YAML `${db.user}` is just a normal scalar. The tag `tag:yaml` is as inappropriate as the `tag:ASCII` would be for this question. Inappropriate tagging is a waste of other peoples time.

Comment: He is using Hydra, which in turn is using OmegaConf, which supports  key interpolation.

https://omegaconf.readthedocs.io/en/2.1_branch/usage.html#variable-interpolation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OmegaConf interpolations are resolved when you access the field. To see the resolved value, add resolve=True to the call `OmegaConf.to_yaml()`:

```py
print(OmegaConf.to_yaml(cfg, resolve=True))
```

Or just access the field (`cfg.test_key`).

As a side note, I recommend that you go over the [documentation of OmegaConf](https://omegaconf.readthedocs.io/en/2.3_branch/).